# Nested loop for pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a database with consists of multiple dates corresponding to each ID. Now I want to iterate over each ID and find the difference between the i and i+1 dates to flag the data based on certain values.
For example:

```
ID      date

0        12.01.2012

0        14.02.2012

0        15.09.2013

1        13.01.2011

1        15.08.2012
```

For ID 0 I want to find the difference of consecutive dates and compare them with a condition to flag the database based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
res = df['date'].apply(lambda x : df['date']-x)
res.columns = df.id.tolist()
res.index=df.id.tolist()
```

for input:

```
        date  id
0 2019-01-01   0
1 2019-01-06   0
2 2019-01-01   0
3 2019-01-04   1
```

Output will be:

```
        0      0       0       1
0  0 days 5 days  0 days  3 days
0 -5 days 0 days -5 days -2 days
0  0 days 5 days  0 days  3 days
1 -3 days 2 days -3 days  0 days
```

for consecutive difference you can use:

```
df["diff"]=df.groupby("id").diff()
```

input:

```
    date    id
0   1984-10-18  0
1   1980-07-19  0
2   1972-04-16  0
3   1969-04-05  1
4   1967-05-29  1
5   1985-07-13  2
```

output:

```
     date      id   diff
0   1984-10-18  0   NaT
1   1980-07-19  0   -1552 days
2   1972-04-16  0   -3016 days
3   1969-04-05  1   NaT
4   1967-05-29  1   -677 days
5   1985-07-13  2   NaT
```

Comment: Thank you but I want my answer in a list form not in a matrix. The ID's should not be connected.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean can you provide some example or explain a bit on this.

Comment: Basically in the example that I have given in the question : the algorithm should take into account ID-0 and should return 33 days,579 days (because it has 3 data so consecutive difference should be 2 data points) and then go to ID-1 and do the same thing!

Comment: I have made a few changes , is this what you are looking for?